# Dynamic Style sheet file in AURA & LWC for branding

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, community

We wanted to show different branding color to the community portal. We can do if the community portal is static template, we can set the branding version in community app builder. But our community portal is custom template . So we need to display different color of theme like background color, forecolor, etc based on teh logged in user. So we have this in our backend object.

In .NET we can have have 3 css file as green,red and yellow and we can load the style css based on teh profile/value we get from db and load it. How can we do it in aura component & lwc to meet the same approach?
let me know if any approaches to take care.

Thanks

Comment: Hi,
we able to achieve dynamic branding to the community portal with custom template and static files of css and load the css files & logo dynamically to the portal.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could change the colours using the Theme section of the Experience builder and/or Theme settings for the community.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is based on profile/role and other.. but we dont want to tied up with these... it is dynamic for each member wise...we are are tying. as the change in community builder will not support.

Comment: Hi,
we able to achieve dynamic branding to the community portal with custom template and static files of css and load the css files & logo dynamically to the portal.

Thanks